# How to identify a "hw.machine" identifier reliable?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, device, detection

I'm looking for the most official source to complete/maintain this method:

```
-(NSString*)platformString
{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"iPhone 4 (Other Carrier)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4 CDMA";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 WiFi";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 GSM";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 CDMA";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 CDMAS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini Wifi";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad mini (Cellular ATT)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad mini (Cellular Verizon)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 WiFi";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 CDMA";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 GSM";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 Wifi";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 3 (Cellular ATT)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 3 (Cellular Verizon)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad 4 WiFi";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad 4 GSM";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"])      return @"iPad 4 CDMA";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unknown: %@", platform];
}
```

**Does Apple have some statement about this somewhere?**

Or an explorous person with a decent research somewhere?

---

Fo clarification, I'm using this code under the hood:

```
-(NSString*)getSysInfoByName:(char*) typeSpecifier
{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname(typeSpecifier, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

    char *answer = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname(typeSpecifier, answer, &size, NULL, 0);

    NSString *results = [NSString stringWithCString:answer encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    free(answer);
    return results;
}

-(NSString*)platform
{ return [self getSysInfoByName:"hw.machine"]; }
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider this off-topic.

Comment: Side note - it would be so much easier if you create a dictionary (in code or a plist) for these values instead of having 49 `if` statements.

Comment: There is nothing official for this. You are at the mercy of others providing these details as they change.

Comment: @rmaddy In the meanwhile I just started to implement that way. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some non-official source I've found so far:

[**Models - The iPhone Wiki**](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models)

[**iClarified - iPhone** - Where To Download iPhone Firmware Files From](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=750)

[**iClarified - iPad** - Where To Download iPad Firmware Files From](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=8500)

[**iClarified - iPod touch** - Where to Download iPod touch Firmware Files From](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=757)

Still looking for a more official source, though.

---

Just extracted from iPhone Wiki (up till iPhone 5S, iPad Air):

```
-(NSDictionary*)deviceModelDataForMachineIDs
{
    return @{

         //iPad.
         @"iPad1,1" : @[ @"iPad 1G", @"Wi-Fi / GSM", @"A1219 / A1337" ],
         @"iPad2,1" : @[ @"iPad 2", @"Wi-Fi", @"A1395" ],
         @"iPad2,2" : @[ @"iPad 2", @"GSM", @"A1396" ],
         @"iPad2,3" : @[ @"iPad 2", @"CDMA", @"A1397" ],
         @"iPad2,4" : @[ @"iPad 2", @"Wi-Fi Rev A", @"A1395" ],
         @"iPad2,5" : @[ @"iPad mini", @"Wi-Fi", @"A1432" ],
         @"iPad2,6" : @[ @"iPad mini", @"GSM", @"A1454" ],
         @"iPad2,7" : @[ @"iPad mini", @"GSM+CDMA", @"A1455" ],
         @"iPad3,1" : @[ @"iPad 3", @"Wi-Fi", @"A1416" ],
         @"iPad3,2" : @[ @"iPad 3", @"GSM+CDMA", @"A1403" ],
         @"iPad3,3" : @[ @"iPad 3", @"GSM", @"A1430" ],
         @"iPad3,4" : @[ @"iPad 4", @"Wi-Fi", @"A1458" ],
         @"iPad3,5" : @[ @"iPad 4", @"GSM", @"A1459" ],
         @"iPad3,6" : @[ @"iPad 4", @"GSM+CDMA", @"A1460" ],
         @"iPad4,1" : @[ @"iPad Air", @"Wi‑Fi", @"A1474" ],
         @"iPad4,2" : @[ @"iPad Air", @"Cellular", @"A1475" ],
         @"iPad4,4" : @[ @"iPad mini 2", @"Wi‑Fi", @"A1489" ],
         @"iPad4,5" : @[ @"iPad mini 2", @"Cellular", @"A1517" ],
         @"iPad4,6" : @[ @"iPad mini 2", @"N/A", @"A1491" ],
         @"iPad4,7" : @[ @"iPad mini 3", @"N/A", @"A1599" ],
         @"iPad4,8" : @[ @"iPad mini 3", @"N/A", @"A1600" ],
         @"iPad4,9" : @[ @"iPad mini 3", @"N/A", @"A1601" ],
         @"iPad5,3" : @[ @"iPad Air 2", @"N/A", @"A1566" ],
         @"iPad5,4" : @[ @"iPad Air 2", @"N/A", @"A1567" ],

         //iPhone.
         @"iPhone1,1" : @[ @"iPhone 2G", @"GSM", @"A1203" ],
         @"iPhone1,2" : @[ @"iPhone 3G", @"GSM", @"A1241 / A13241" ],
         @"iPhone2,1" : @[ @"iPhone 3GS", @"GSM", @"A1303 / A13251" ],
         @"iPhone3,1" : @[ @"iPhone 4", @"GSM", @"A1332" ],
         @"iPhone3,2" : @[ @"iPhone 4", @"GSM Rev A", @"-" ],
         @"iPhone3,3" : @[ @"iPhone 4", @"CDMA", @"A1349" ],
         @"iPhone4,1" : @[ @"iPhone 4S", @"GSM+CDMA", @"A1387 / A14311" ],
         @"iPhone5,1" : @[ @"iPhone 5", @"GSM", @"A1428" ],
         @"iPhone5,2" : @[ @"iPhone 5", @"GSM+CDMA", @"A1429 / A14421" ],
         @"iPhone5,3" : @[ @"iPhone 5C", @"GSM", @"A1456 / A1532" ],
         @"iPhone5,4" : @[ @"iPhone 5C", @"Global", @"A1507 / A1516 / A1526 / A1529" ],
         @"iPhone6,1" : @[ @"iPhone 5S", @"GSM", @"A1433 / A1533" ],
         @"iPhone6,2" : @[ @"iPhone 5S", @"Global", @"A1457 / A1518 / A1528 / A1530" ],
         @"iPhone7,2" : @[ @"iPhone 6", @"N/A", @"A1549 / A1586" ],
         @"iPhone7,1" : @[ @"iPhone 6 Plus", @"N/A", @"A1522 / A1524" ],

         //iPod.
         @"iPod1,1" : @[ @"iPod touch 1G", @"-", @"A1213" ],
         @"iPod2,1" : @[ @"iPod touch 2G", @"-", @"A1288" ],
         @"iPod3,1" : @[ @"iPod touch 3G", @"-", @"A1318" ],
         @"iPod4,1" : @[ @"iPod touch 4G", @"-", @"A1367" ],
         @"iPod5,1" : @[ @"iPod touch 5G", @"-", @"A1421 / A1509" ]

    };
}
```

It is now part of [eppz!kit on GitHub](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit) along with the rest of the code. Implemented in [`EPPZDevice.h`](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit/blob/master/eppz!kit/EPPZDevice.h) class.

Comment: Gonna change on Sept. 5 anyway. :)

Comment: Updated with new devices.

Comment: here is some more WIKIs in wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iPad_models
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iPhone_models
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iPod_models

Answer (score 4):

iOS devices are asking following Apple page for update packages:

http://mesu.apple.com/assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate.xml

This XML contains "SupportedDevices" key with identifier values like "iPhone6,1", "iPhone5,3". "Model" key is printed on the back side of the iOS device or you can find them on apple webpages e.g.:

http://www.apple.com/legal/rfexposure/iphone5,4/cs/

Apple is also updating its support page with all models:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3939

Comment: That XML is awesome. Though it is not meant for third parties, I mean it is subject of change. Great source to check anyway.