# Check iPhone device version fails on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to detect on which iPhone my app is running.
I found this, here at stackoverflow:

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

But this doesn't work for me. When I have an iPhone6 in standardmode (not zoomed) it says it is an iPhone5.
I also tested

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
```

but this returns everytime 320.

In simulator it works perfect but on device it fails.

Can someone help me to find out which iPhone is used?

best regards

Comment: If you didn't provide launch_screen.xib or launch image for iPhone 6 then in iPhone6 the app is scaled.
Please check height of your status bar when your app is running, if it says 20 and it looks taller than usual, app is scaled.

Comment: I have added a launch_screen.xib. Without it doesn't work at simulator, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on screen size, why not use "`[[UIDevice curentDevice] model]`" instead?

[Here's a tutorial that might help you out](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/better-code-determine-device-types-and-ios-versions/).

And if "`[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]`" isn't detailed enough for you, there's also "`sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machineNameAsCString, &size, NULL, 0);`", where the tutorial shows how to get a "nice string" (or nice version of the model name) out of it.

[There's also Open Source available that you can drop in to determine the Device display name](https://github.com/stephanheilner/UIDevice-DisplayName).

Comment: With this I cant find out if it is an iPhone6. It just say x86_64.

Comment: Yes you can.  Going via "`hw.machine`", "`iPhone7,2`" is iPhone 6 and "`iPhone7,1`" is iPhone 6 Plus.  [More information can be found in this very related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414032/how-to-identify-a-hw-machine-identifier-reliable).

Comment: Yes you are right, it was my fault. hw.machine works.